# order by id not working with me

Tags: php, mysql

I have made " news & updates " simple script

my query is:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM a_commants WHERE postid='$postid' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10");
```

it shows last comment

i want to make it show all comments or at least 10 comments

if i change it to:

> $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM a_commants WHERE
>   postid='$postid'");

it shows first comment only

idk whats wrong :(

Comment: There's only one comment for given postid?

Comment: make sure you have more than one record for `$postid` value.

Comment: i have three records for postid http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/4245/ulht.png

Comment: probably you have one comment for given post so far ? Add more comments for that post and try again. OR show the code where you are displaying the records. Probably you need to use for-each/while loop etc..

Comment: You put commEnts in a commAnts table. Isn't this confusing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is in your php code, not MySQL.
The query seems fine, as long as you have more than one comment, but it seems that you are not iterating through results, just printing the first row you get from db.

This should show last 10 comments:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM a_commants WHERE postid='$postid' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ // iterate through results
    print_r($row); // print the row
}
```

And you should definitely [switch to mysqli or PDO, and sanitize your inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496).
The mysql_* functions are deprecated and going to be removed from PHP.

Comment: Did you get more than one row?